# Overwrite s3 data using Glue job in AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to save my Glue job output to S3 using following code snippet

```
output_table = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=table,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://brand-code-mappings", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)
```

I want to overwrite all the objects that are already present in S3 bucket instead of appending to them.

I have tried making following changes, but nothing seems to work.

```
table.toDF()
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("parquet")
    .partitionBy()
    .save('s3://brand-code-mappings')
```

```
table.toDF()
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .parquet("s3://brand-code-mappings")
```

Please help on how i can overwrite already existing objects in the S3 bucket with the Glue output.

I am using Glue 3.0- which supports Spark 3.1, Scala 2 and Python 3.

Thanks,
Anamika